# Focus of Raspberry Camera is too close

Tags: camera, webcam

I'm using the 5mp Cam on my rev. b rPi and I'm having trouble with the focus length. The usual problem is that the focus isn't close enough, my problem is that the focus is too short. I'm using it as a webcam in my garden and the length is about 30m. The focus is at about 0.5m so most of the picture is a bit blurred through this. Is there any possibility to adjust the focus to get the focus in the middle of the picture?

I've heard about attaching an additional lense to the camera, but does this also work to increase the focus length?

I've set the quality of the image to 89% while converting it for the upload, if this is an important information you need.
I've included a picture where you can see, how my focus is set.[image: The yellow spray bottle is focused, the garden behind is a bit blurred.]

Comment: Have you tried moving the lens manually? http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Birdbox-Camera/step3/Adjust-the-Focal-Length-of-the-camera/ (If you can move it in, you should be able to move it out).

Comment: Thank your for that link! Am I right that I need to remove the glue completely? After that, do I need to put new glue on?

Comment: I  haven't done it -- that's just the first thing I found, and it makes a lot of sense.   You can't actually see the glue, you just have to turn the lens to break it.  I just tried to that with mine using a pair of tweezers, but it is hard to do and I am a little trepidatious about slipping and scratching the lens...so I will have to think for a bit.  If you have a better toolkit, and secure it to something first, it might be easier.

Comment: Moving the focal point of the lens isn't too hard (we've removed the lenses on a couple of cameras now for microscope experiments) but you do need to be careful; I have heard of people breaking their camera module doing this (on the other hand, they're not hugely expensive to replace!). One quick correction: the quality isn't a percentage measure (like 89%) - it's an [arbitrary measure](http://photo.net/learn/jpeg/#qual) and not even comparable between products.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it manually: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/infrared-bird-box/

This involves actually turning the lens.

Comment: I've done this, and it's not hard.  But I had a low-magnification microscope sitting next to the camera board anyway.